# How to convert XML to Java Object in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I wondering that which is the best libray to convert XML to Java Object easily.

I have used [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html) but i am not getting what i want.

I want to pass this xml.

http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=ttc&r=54

Please, suggest me some good library.

Comment: use gson. http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) and [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) allows you to convert an XML Schema (XSD) file into a collection of Java classes. This may be more "structured" than the `XMLEncoder`/`Serializable` approach that Andy's (excellent, by the way) answer provides.